# How to create a SQL table without the use of INSERT function?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The aim is to have a table with only one field called `FieldA` and with only two values ("Value One" and "Value Two").

[image]

I would like to don't use `CREATE` or `INSERT` functions.

I would like to use a code like this:

`SELECT ("Value One", "Value Two") AS FieldA;`

But what is the right syntax to use?

Comment: Please read [What is the X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and edit your question accordingly.  There isn't a way that I know of to create a table without using CREATE or the user interface of Access, so you're going to need to tell us why you need this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather painful in MS Access.  Let me assume that you have some table somewhere, say `t`.  You can do:

```
select top (1) "Value One" as fieldA
from t
union all
select top (1) "Value Two"
from t;
```

You can then use `select into` if you actually want to create a table, rather than a result set.

Comment: 1+ Interesting solution Gordon - it's odd that the JET engine can happily evaluate `select "Value One" as FieldA` and `select "Value Two" as FieldA` but not `select "Value One" as FieldA union all select "Value Two" as FieldA` or even `select * from (select "Value One" as FieldA) a union all select * from (select "Value Two" as FieldA) b`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the 2 values in a table of your database 
then what you need is not possible in **Access** with a single statement.  
You can execute:

```
SELECT "Value One" AS FieldA INTO tablename;
```

to create the table and add the 1st row,  
but next you'll have to use `INSERT` to add the 2nd row

```
INSERT INTO tablename (FieldA) VALUES ('Value Two');
```